# R lm() solves a singular system without error

Tags: r, lm

To reproduce

```
set.seed(1)
N <- 100
x <- rep(1, N)
covar <- matrix(rnorm(N * 10), N)
lm(x ~ covar)
```

Because of the intercept, I would expect this to be singular and not solvable.
Instead, I just get very small values for the coefficients of `covar`.

Anyone knows a way around this?

---

Edit: what is singular is

```
model.matrix(~ ., data = cbind.data.frame(x, covar))
```

(first two columns are all 1s)

Comment: What matrix would you expect to be singular, covar$^T$covar?

Comment: @Dave Please see my edit.

Comment: You are make much out of nothing.  (1) Inspect `zapsmall(coefficients(lm(x ~ covar)))`.  (2) Type `summary(lm(x ~ covar))`.  Together these should fully answer your question.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution I came up with (testing if residuals are almost 0). The problem is that you get an R2 of 50% when the outcome has no variation, that can be very misleading.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why this should not be solvable. You regress, as you point out, a constant on a constant, which is "generated" to affect the dependent variable with a coefficient of one, plus other variables which are generated in a way so as to have nothing to do with the dependent variable. So a unit coefficient on the constant term and zero coefficients for the rest seem precisely what to expect. That they are not exactly zero is numerical noise to me.